# How to execute a set of query after seconds in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I'm building a game as my final project of university after some short research on internet I've used something like Waitforsecond()  in unity but it didn't work, anyone know the solution, plesase help!

Comment: Where did you look with your short research? Did you check out the [Unity3D Forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/) and [Q&A site](http://answers.unity3d.com/)? Did you check out the [Unity Docs on Coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html)? Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use coroutines for this:

```
void CallCoroutine()
{
    StartCoroutine(PauseandGo(5));
}

IEnumerator PauseandGo(int seconds)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of stuff (call a method after X seconds without arguments), [*MonoBehaviour.Invoke*](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) is simpler to use and more readable than using coroutines.

```
Invoke("doSomething", 5);
```

*will call doSomething() after 5 seconds*